# Como usar Ajax com AntiForgeryToken?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Segue o código:

```
//AntiForgeryToken
function gettoken() {
    var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
    token = $(token).val();
    return token;
}
```

Ajax e formData:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
var file1 = document.getElementById("coverFile").files[0];

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ação controller',
    data: {formData, gettoken}, <- como fazer aqui
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response) {

        }
    }
    ,
    error: function (request, status, error)
    {
        alert('Error')
    }
});
```

PartialView:

```
<form id="myform">
    <div class="modal-body">

      Campos...

    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Criar" />
</form>
```

Como fazer AntiForgeryToken via Ajax para proteger contra falsificação ? Alguma solução ?

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer? Não explicou nada na pergunta...

Comment: seria algo desse tipo? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você vai precisar capturar o valor do token antes de enviar, dessa forma

```
var form = $('#Id-do-Formulario'); //Tanto faz a forma de capturar
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
```

Exemplo

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}

<div id="id-da-div" data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    Ajax com ValidateAntiForgeryToken
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#id-da-div').submit(function () {
        var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
                formData: dadosParaEnviar 
            },
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Ou, você pode pode capturar o valor com uma função

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gettoken() {
        var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
        token = $(token).val();
        return token;
    }
</script>
```

E usá-lo assim

```
//ajax
data: {
    __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(),
    formData: dados
},
```

Comment: como eu faço com o meu data para enviar esta dando erro  

      data: JSON.stringify(todos_servicos), // passar os parametros fiz assim:             data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(),
               todos_servicos
        }, // passar os parametros

Comment: @DenilsonCarlos que erro está dando ?

Comment: @DenilsonCarlos, Coloca assim: `data: {  __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(), formData: todos_servicos },`

Comment: se  eu usar o data: JSON.stringify(todos_servicos), ele envia para o meu controller todas as informações contidas no meu "todos_servicos" , se eu colocar data: { __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(), todos_servicos }, não envia e da erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" na linha do data.

Comment: @DenilsonCarlos cria novo post(pergunta), o que está acontecendo o seu problema.